# Javascript find and replace dom string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use replace method of javascript to replace some html string. I stored a dom string by fetching .outerHTML and want to replace a perticular word with the string. Here is my outerHTML dom which i fetch with javascript :

```
<figure class="image" onclick="someMethod('btbjwkjpuynyzdijsvf5.jpg', 'Title','$caption', 'image','other params')">
    <img id="45435435345" src="btbjwkjpuynyzdijsvf5.jpg" caption="$caption" title="title">
    <figcaption>$caption</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Here is want to replace all $caption with real caption which i fetch from database later. But this is not working. I tried on browser console to store this string on variable but it giving error after single quote (which is available inside function parameter). So i think it is having a problem with unrecognized string value. How can i resolve this issue so i can replace $caption value from string.

Comment: What you're trying to do isn't a good idea. Don't pass the `$caption` variable to the function at all. Instead, retrieve it within `someMethod()` itself - presumably though AJAX if it's coming from the server

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  someMethod() is function which is only used for open image on fullscreen. so i passed all require parameter for open image with detail like title and caption. but when on creater when i load image i want to caption update which is fetch from server side.

Comment: and this DOM is a string. This will saved with ckeditor, i am using ckeidtor to store this value, and this is image with some content.

Comment: Have you tried replacing attribute instead? `$([caption='$caption']).attr('caption', value)`

Comment: @Rajesh i cant do this because there may have many images with different captions. and i cant identify index of particular caption,

Comment: Note: DOM manipulation is always better than string manipulation. Also setting innerHTML/outerHTML can will erase all eventListeners attached to them. So if possible, try to manipulate DOM

Comment: @Rajesh i am using ckeditor and angularjs for that. so i am storing all content with images in database, and here is one click event method on image  so it will open image on popup on full screen. so i am passing related parameters inside function. but i have requirement to update caption which i updated before on resource collection. so it will update when ckeditor loaded. So i want to trying replacing with string.

Comment: @Rajesh instead of doing this. do u have any other suggestion so i can change caption. can i put reference inside function as parameter so i can handle it in ckeditor callback?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good practice but instead you can use a javascript templating engine

```js
$("#myDiv").html($("#myDiv").html().replace(/\$caption/g,'My caption'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">
 <figure class="image" onclick="someMethod('btbjwkjpuynyzdijsvf5.jpg', 'Title','$caption', 'image','other params')">
    <img id="45435435345" src="btbjwkjpuynyzdijsvf5.jpg" caption="$caption" title="title">
    <figcaption>$caption</figcaption>
</figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the attribute selector

```
$("[caption]").attr("caption", myCaptionText)
```

you should ofcourse be a bit more specific so you don't over write every instance of the caption attribute

```
$(".specificParent [caption]").attr("caption", myCaptionText)
```